# How to add all quantity field in an array of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show how many items there are in a basket, so each items have `qtyField: value` instead of showing the `arr.length` of the  basket.

Like in ecommerce, if you have 1 apple in the basket and the basket count reflects the amount of item(s) you have.

```js
var updateCartItem = {
        Products: [
      {  
           "product_idField":"96031",
           "skuField":"321005Y-00100-ITM",
           "nameField":"Cooper Sunglasses",
           "priceField":"75.0000",
           "qtyField":3,
           "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
           "$$hashKey":"object:8"
        },
          {  
           "product_idField":"another",
           "skuField":"another-ITM",
           "nameField":"Pony Sunglasses",
           "priceField":"75.0000",
           "qtyField":1,
           "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
           "$$hashKey":"object:8"
        },
        {  
           "product_idField":"empty",
           "skuField":"empty-ITM",
           "nameField":"Nobody wants it Sunglasses",
           "priceField":"75.0000",
           "qtyField":1,
           "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
           "$$hashKey":"object:8"
        }
     ]
    }
  
 updateCartItem.Products.forEach(function (element) {
                console.log(element.qtyField);
            }, this);
```

In my object above there are 3 items but `qtyField` have different amounts, so I want add all the `qtyField` values and show the total count.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example):

```js
var updateCartItem = {
        Products: [
      {  
           "product_idField":"96031",
           "skuField":"321005Y-00100-ITM",
           "nameField":"Cooper Sunglasses",
           "priceField":"75.0000",
           "qtyField":3,
           "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
           "$$hashKey":"object:8"
        },
          {  
           "product_idField":"another",
           "skuField":"another-ITM",
           "nameField":"Pony Sunglasses",
           "priceField":"75.0000",
           "qtyField":1,
           "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
           "$$hashKey":"object:8"
        },
        {  
           "product_idField":"empty",
           "skuField":"empty-ITM",
           "nameField":"Nobody wants it Sunglasses",
           "priceField":"75.0000",
           "qtyField":1,
           "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
           "$$hashKey":"object:8"
        }
     ]
    }
    
var total = updateCartItem.Products.reduce((acc,prod) => {
    return acc + prod.qtyField
}, 0);
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 let total = 0;
 updateCartItem.Products.forEach(function (element) {
           total += element.qtyField;
           console.log(total);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is called map-reduce.

Try this:

```js
var updateCartItem = {
        Products: [
      {  
           "product_idField":"96031",
           "skuField":"321005Y-00100-ITM",
           "nameField":"Cooper Sunglasses",
           "priceField":"75.0000",
           "qtyField":3,
           "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
           "$$hashKey":"object:8"
        },
          {  
           "product_idField":"another",
           "skuField":"another-ITM",
           "nameField":"Pony Sunglasses",
           "priceField":"75.0000",
           "qtyField":1,
           "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
           "$$hashKey":"object:8"
        },
        {  
           "product_idField":"empty",
           "skuField":"empty-ITM",
           "nameField":"Nobody wants it Sunglasses",
           "priceField":"75.0000",
           "qtyField":1,
           "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
           "$$hashKey":"object:8"
        }
     ]
    }
  
 var sum = updateCartItem.Products
 .map(p=>p.qtyField)
 .reduce((total, num) => total + num);
 console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to sum up all quantities? Your cart can be reduced to it:

```
var total=updateCartItem.Products.reduce((a,b)=>a+b.qtyField,0);
```

```js
var updateCartItem = {
  Products: [{
      "product_idField": "96031",
      "skuField": "321005Y-00100-ITM",
      "nameField": "Cooper Sunglasses",
      "priceField": "75.0000",
      "qtyField": 3,
      "qtyFieldSpecified": true,
      "$$hashKey": "object:8"
    },
    {
      "product_idField": "another",
      "skuField": "another-ITM",
      "nameField": "Pony Sunglasses",
      "priceField": "75.0000",
      "qtyField": 1,
      "qtyFieldSpecified": true,
      "$$hashKey": "object:8"
    },
    {
      "product_idField": "empty",
      "skuField": "empty-ITM",
      "nameField": "Nobody wants it Sunglasses",
      "priceField": "75.0000",
      "qtyField": 1,
      "qtyFieldSpecified": true,
      "$$hashKey": "object:8"
    }
  ]
};

var total = updateCartItem.Products.reduce((a, b) => a + b.qtyField, 0);
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var updateCartItem = {
        Products: [
      {  
           "product_idField":"96031",
           "skuField":"321005Y-00100-ITM",
           "nameField":"Cooper Sunglasses",
           "priceField":"75.0000",
           "qtyField":3,
           "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
           "$$hashKey":"object:8"
        },
          {  
           "product_idField":"another",
           "skuField":"another-ITM",
           "nameField":"Pony Sunglasses",
           "priceField":"75.0000",
           "qtyField":1,
           "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
           "$$hashKey":"object:8"
        },
        {  
           "product_idField":"empty",
           "skuField":"empty-ITM",
           "nameField":"Nobody wants it Sunglasses",
           "priceField":"75.0000",
           "qtyField":1,
           "qtyFieldSpecified":true,
           "$$hashKey":"object:8"
        }
     ]
    }
  var total = 0;
  
 updateCartItem.Products.forEach(function (element) {
                console.log(element.qtyField);
                 total += element.qtyField;
            }, this);
 console.log('Total : '+total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following

```
updateCartItem.Products.map(function(e){return e.qtyField}).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```